# Hosting Dovecot and Postfix Behind nginx?

Tags: email, postfix, nginx, ssl, dovecot

So I'm looking at setting up `postfix` and `dovecot` on a server that is currently hosting some web-sites via `nginx`, and I've stumbled upon the `mail {}` configuration option for `nginx`, but I'm having a hard time finding concrete examples that really show how I can use it.

Basically what I would like to do is have `dovecot` and `postfix` listen locally via sockets/ports on the current system (or another on the same local network if I move them in future), with `nginx` handling all of the actual external connections. Is this possible?

If so, what I'd also like to know is whether it's possible to use such a setup to support multiple domains?

For example, could I make something like the following work, and if-so, how?

```
mail {
    server_name mail.some.domain;

    ssl_certificate /some/path/mail.some.domain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /some/path/mail.some.domain.key;

    server {
        listen :587 ssl;
        listen [::]:587 ssl;
        protocol smtp;
        # somehow point this to postfix
    }

    server {
        listen :993 ssl;
        listen [::]:993 ssl;
        protocol imap;
        # somehow point this to dovecot
    }
}

mail {
    server_name mail.another.domain;

    ssl_certificate /some/path/mail.another.domain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /some/path/mail.another.domain.key;

    server {
        listen :587 ssl;
        listen [::]:587 ssl;
        protocol smtp;
        # somehow point this to postfix
    }

    server {
        listen :993 ssl;
        listen [::]:993 ssl;
        protocol imap;
        # somehow point this to dovecot
    }
}
```

i.e- `nginx` providing external connections for IMAP and SMTP for each domain, and routing to `postfix` and `dovecot` which are both configured with the appropriate virtual users, domains etc.

I know `dovecot` can handle multiple domains with individual certificates, so if it's easier to configure it separately then I can do that, but I'd like to be able to point different domains to `postfix` as well, without having to use a single certificate for all of my e-mail domains.

If possible I'd appreciate an answer that competes one of the above `mail` blocks, plus any configuration changes I might need for `dovecot` and/or `postfix` to work in this setup.